# Eclipse autocomplete behaviour like intellij - Choose with ENTER not SPACE

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've just configured eclipse to suggest auto complete, 
so now just by typing (without ctrl+space), it suggests auto completions for me:
[image]
But unlike intellij, I want to CHOOSE the selected auto complete only by pressing 'ENTER', and not by pressing 'SPACE'.

Eclipse:

If I write 'Pri' and press 'SPACE' I get 'PrintWriter'

Intellij:

If I write 'Pri' and press 'SPACE' i get 'Pri' (and for 'PrintWri' also gets 'PrintWri')

I will get 'PrintWriter' only if I select it and press 'ENTER'

How can I configure it at Eclipse ? Thanks

Comment: If you want this functionality in eclipse or intellij ?

Comment: I want it in ECLIPSE

Comment: sorry not a eclipse lover here :)

Comment: You should remove the `intellij-idea` tag.

Comment: @Bajal ok it's done

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content Assist and check `Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'` and that'll do what you're looking for.